# changing the style of sidebar

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I am just a newbie in wordpress.I want the colour of the sidebar widget will be different in different pages. As the id and class are both same in every pages don't know how to change that.Is there any solution of it?Any help will be highly appriciable...

Answer (score 1):

if you are using (a child of) twenty ten, then the theme will use [`body_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) and have a unique css class for each page; use that to style the color of the sidebar widgets; 
example:

```
.page-id-23 #primary.widget-area { color: #123edf; }
```